# Detect if running with administrator privileges under Windows XP

Tags: windows, ruby, command-line, privileges

I am trying to work out how to detect whether a user is running with admin rights under Windows XP. This is fairly easy to do in Vista/Win7 thanks to the **whoami** command. Here's a snippet in Ruby for how to do it under Vista:

*Note, the following link now incorporates the solution suggested by muteW*

http://gist.github.com/65931

The trouble is, whoami doesn't come with Windows XP and so the above linked method will always return false on WinXP, even if we're running as an administrator.

So, does anyone know of a way to detect whether we're running as an admin under Windows XP using Ruby, command-line tools, batch-files, or even third-party (needs to be open source, really) tools?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This will detect if the user is running in elevated mode (eg a command prompt that was "Run As" Administrator).  It relies on the fact that you require admin privileges to read the LOCAL SERVICE account reg key:

```
reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19"
```

this will return a non-zero error code if it cannot be read, and zero if it can.
Works from XP up...

Comment: And to anyone who uses C++, system() returns 1 if the command above fails and 0 if it succeeds; meaning it returns 0 if the user has admin rights. Very good answer, Peter. Thanks!

Comment: Or, in C/C++: call RegOpenKey(HKEY_USERS, "S-1-5-19", &key) and check for success.

Answer (score 11):

If you run

```
>net localgroup administrators
```

in a command shell you should get the list of administrator accounts in Windows XP. Simply parse and scan the output to check for the particular user account you want. For e.g. to check if the current user is an administrator you could do -

```
>net localgroup administrators | find "%USERNAME%"
```

Comment: This only validates that the username is in the Admin group - it does not detect if the current session has admin rights.  For example on Win 7 with UAC, a command prompt runs by default as non-admin and the above command will incorrectly report the session as Admin. See my solution for something a little more reliable

Answer (score 7):

Piskvor option its fine, or check this url
http://weseetips.com/2008/04/16/how-to-check-whether-current-user-have-administrator-privilege/

this is the code in that page

```
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY NtAuthority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
PSID AdministratorsGroup;
// Initialize SID.
if( !AllocateAndInitializeSid( &NtAuthority,
                               2,
                               SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,
                               DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                               &AdministratorsGroup))
{
    // Initializing SID Failed.
    return false;
}
// Check whether the token is present in admin group.
BOOL IsInAdminGroup = FALSE;
if( !CheckTokenMembership( NULL,
                           AdministratorsGroup,
                           &IsInAdminGroup ))
{
    // Error occurred.
    IsInAdminGroup = FALSE;
}
// Free SID and return.
FreeSid(AdministratorsGroup);
return IsInAdminGroup;
```

Comment: its made in C using the WINDOWS API, so you dont need anything else to running this, just compile it

Comment: Note that this will return FALSE if called from a Vista program running in an administrator account if the process was not launched with 'run as administrator'.

Comment: thats a Vista issue. maybe you could add a differente check in the same program for Vista OS...

Comment: For future reference, the above code is taken from:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376389%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [CheckTokenMembership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376389(VS.85).aspx) method. There is a sample there of IsUserAdmin() implementation plus some other useful community feedback on when that function does not return what is expected and what to do to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

This will find out without shelling out:

```
require 'win32/registry'

is_admin = false
begin
  Win32::Registry::HKEY_USERS.open('S-1-5-19') {|reg| }
  is_admin = true
rescue
end
```

The strategy is similar to Peter's, but with less overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the better (PowerShell) way of doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16617861/863980

In one line, you can say (copy/paste in posh and it will work):

```
(@(([ADSI]"WinNT://./Administrators,group").psbase.Invoke("Members")) | `
foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -contains "Administrator"
```

=> returns `True` when user belongs to Administrators group (as opposed to checking user IS Administrator)

(Note: backtick or grave accent ` escapes the carriage return in PowerShell, in Ruby it executes the shell commands, like C++'s system('command')..)

So in Ruby, you can say (copy/paste in irb):

```
def is_current_user_local_admin?
  return `powershell "(@(([ADSI]'WinNT://./Administrators,group').psbase.Invoke('Members')) | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember('Name', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -contains 'Administrator'"`.include? "True"
end
```

Don't know the (even better) WMI way of doing it though. With that, you could have done something like (in Ruby again):

```
require 'win32ole'
wmi = WIN32OLE.connect('WinNT://./Administrators,group')
# don't know what should come here...
```