# How do I check if a user has local admin privileges in win32

Tags: c++, winapi

How do I check if a user has local admin privileges in win32 from c++

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560366/detect-if-running-with-administrator-privileges-under-windows-xp
Answers point to win32 api solutions.

Comment: Not exactly the same with UAC under Vista. "Running with admin privileges" now implies the user has admin rights and used them when starting a process.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just found [IsUserAnAdmin()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in shlobj.h which does the job for me.

Comment: Being an admin does not mean that the current process runs with elevated privileges

Comment: Caution: IsUserAnAdmin() is deprecated: "It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions." Last supported client version: Windows Vista!

Comment: oli fortunately I only needed it for XP support, for Vista and later I can check for elevation.

Comment: only works between XP and Vista, no Windows 7 8 or 10

Answer (score 5):

You might need more than that to deal with elevation and such like...

I do it like this....

```
bool CProcessToken::IsUserAnAdmin() const
{
#if _WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600 

   bool isAdmin = false;

   DWORD bytesUsed = 0;

   TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE tokenElevationType;

   if (!::GetTokenInformation(m_hToken, TokenElevationType, &tokenElevationType, sizeof(tokenElevationType), &bytesUsed))
   {
      const DWORD lastError = ::GetLastError();

      throw CWin32Exception(_T("CProcessToken::IsUserAnAdmin() - GetTokenInformation - TokenElevationType"), lastError);
   }

   if (tokenElevationType == TokenElevationTypeLimited)
   {
      CSmartHandle hUnfilteredToken;

      if (!::GetTokenInformation(m_hToken, TokenLinkedToken, reinterpret_cast<void *>(hUnfilteredToken.GetHandle()), sizeof(HANDLE), &bytesUsed))
      {
         const DWORD lastError = ::GetLastError();

         throw CWin32Exception(_T("CProcessToken::IsUserAnAdmin() - GetTokenInformation - TokenLinkedToken"), lastError);
      }

      BYTE adminSID[SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE];

      DWORD sidSize = sizeof(adminSID);

      if (!::CreateWellKnownSid(WinBuiltinAdministratorsSid, 0, &adminSID, &sidSize))
      {
         const DWORD lastError = ::GetLastError();

         throw CWin32Exception(_T("CProcessToken::IsUserAnAdmin() - CreateWellKnownSid"), lastError);
      }

      BOOL isMember = FALSE;

      if (::CheckTokenMembership(hUnfilteredToken, &adminSID, &isMember))
      {
         const DWORD lastError = ::GetLastError();

         throw CWin32Exception(_T("CProcessToken::IsUserAnAdmin() - CheckTokenMembership"), lastError);
      }

      isAdmin = (isMember != FALSE);
   }
   else
   {
      isAdmin = ToBool(::IsUserAnAdmin());         
   }

   return isAdmin;

#else
   return ToBool(::IsUserAnAdmin());         
#endif
}
```

I can't remember where I got the information from to write that bit of code though...

Comment: Fortunately I can ignore elevation at the moment as I request elevation in the manifest, this is just for pre Vista installs.

Comment: @Len Holgate do you know if this works for members of a domain admin as well (not just local machine admins, which I verified to be working ok)

Comment: m_hToken is not defined, CWin32Exception is not defined, CSmartHandle is not defined, ToBool() is not defined. So this code only works when _WIN32_WINNT < 0x0600, but uses the deprecated ::IsUserAnAdmin() then.

Comment: It's not supposed to be compilable, it simply shows the API calls to make - fill in the detail yourself.