# win32 api - how to check for user privileges on a remote machine

Tags: c, winapi

given user credentials to either a local account on a remote machine or a domain account, how can i check the user privileges these credentials grant on a remote host ?

i can lookup the SID for the account, but how do i know if, for instance, this account is a members of the administrators group on the remote host ?

i can find plenty of example for checking against the local administrators group (fo example [How do I check if a user has local admin privileges in win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581204/)), but it looks like CreateWellKnownSid only works on the localhost.

any clues/pointers/code samples would be very welcome.

edit: more background on my problem in the comments below.

Comment: That's what the Active Directory API is meant to do.

Comment: the scenario i have in mind is something like psexec - you're given credentials to a remote computer, you copy over a small service executable to IPC$ on the remote host, configure it as a service on the remote host, start it and establish communication with this service which you use to execute stuff.
how can it be that all this can be done without touching the AD API but in order to query for the appropriate permissions to do this i need the AD API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not necessary to perform this step to do the task you are describing, and for various reasons performing this step will not ensure that the task succeeds. For example, the credentials may have permissions on the remote machine, but there may be security software in place which prevents it from succeeding.

The way to solve your problem is to simply do the task using the credentials given, and **check all return values**. If you get STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED it means what it says. If you don't get any errors, well your job is done.

Checking the credentials will ***only*** be useful to assist a user in selecting appropriate credentials. You may just as well check for access to the `\\machine\admin$` share as any other more complicated check.

**That said, here is how to do what you asked**

If the credentials are domain credentials, you will need to look them up in Active Directory. ADSI is good for this from script. Other APIs exist. Get a list of the user's groups.

Then you need to connect to the remote machine using either the NetXXX apis or ADSI WinNT provider. Get a list of members of the Administrators group. If the any of the user's domain accounts are members of the Administrators group, the user is a member.

This can all be done from script using ADSI LDAP and WinNT providers.

**Alternatives**

Everyone who wants to run remote code seems to think that you have to write a service executable, install a service, then start it.

The alternative, which is very easy if you have Admin credentials, is to use the Task Scheduler service. It is easy to use `SCHTASKS.EXE` to create a scheduled task which runs as `SYSTEM`, `LOCAL SERVICE`, `NETWORK SERVICE` or any account whose credentials you have. It can be created without a schedule, then explicitly started, or created with a "once" schedule to run at any time you like, for example in the next few minutes.

If you need to run code on a remote machine, I strongly recommend `SCHTASKS.EXE` not the service method.