# How to create a symlink on Windows via Ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows

Creating symlinks on Ubuntu via `FileUtils.symlink 'X', 'Y'` works while on Windows the following error occurs:

```
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:349:in `symlink': symlink() function is unimplemented on this machine (NotImplementedError)
from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:349:in `block in ln_s'
from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1567:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:347:in `ln_s'
from C:/test/test.rb:7:in `<class:Test>'
from C:/test/test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

As a workaround it is possible to create symlinks on Windows via `mklink`, but I would like to create symlinks on Windows via Ruby as well.

Comment: Did you read the error **symlink() function is unimplemented on this machine (NotImplementedError)**. For windows it is not implemented.

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping if someone knows a workaround via Ruby

Comment: You don't want to use workarounds here, it's best to refactor your code and avoid symlinks in windows.

Comment: @user21033168 I agreed..

Comment: alternatively create a method that makes a system call to `mklink` that would be used if the platform is window$

Comment: There would be permissions issues there. Windows users don't like dealing with symlinks either - they can be frustrating to remove.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. @bjhaid I have embedded `mklink` in the custom function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slightly embarrassed to post this ugly hack, but if you just GOTTA make it work, you can redefine methods and shell out to mklink. mklink is a bit complicated because it isn't a stand-alone program. Mklink is a cmd.exe shell command.

Below is for File class. For FileUtils, you can replace the class name and redefine methods you need as listed [in the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html)

```
require 'open3'

class << File
  alias_method :old_symlink, :symlink
  alias_method :old_symlink?, :symlink?

  def symlink(old_name, new_name)
    #if on windows, call mklink, else self.symlink
    if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin32|cygwin|mingw|bccwin/
      #windows mklink syntax is reverse of unix ln -s
      #windows mklink is built into cmd.exe
      #vulnerable to command injection, but okay because this is a hack to make a cli tool work.
      stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3('cmd.exe', "/c mklink #{new_name} #{old_name}")
      wait_thr.value.exitstatus
    else
      self.old_symlink(old_name, new_name)
    end
  end

  def symlink?(file_name)
    #if on windows, call mklink, else self.symlink
    if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin32|cygwin|mingw|bccwin/
      #vulnerable to command injection because calling with cmd.exe with /c?
      stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3("cmd.exe /c dir #{file_name} | find \"SYMLINK\"")
      wait_thr.value.exitstatus
    else
      self.old_symlink?(file_name)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to run the script in elevated mode:
[Run ruby script in elevated mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268154/run-ruby-script-in-elevated-mode/27954953#27954953)

```
def windows?
  RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw/
end

if windows?
  def FileUtils.symlink source, dest, out = nil
    dest = File.expand_path(dest).gsub(?/, ?\\)
    source = File.expand_path(source).gsub(?/, ?\\)
    opt = File.directory?(source) ? '/d ' : ''
    output = `cmd.exe /c mklink #{opt}"#{dest}" "#{source}"` # & pause`
    out.puts output if out
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this with JRuby 9.1.13.0 (2.3.3) and `FileUtils` seems to handle Windows symlinks now. The following is working if run as administrator. Softlinks should also work without administrator privileges.

```ruby
require 'fileutils'

# Hardlinks work only for files
FileUtils.ln('./dir/file', './link')
# Softlinks to directories are created as symlinkd
FileUtils.ln_s('./dir', './link_dir')
```