# Ruby -FileUtils creating a directory ,permission denied issue on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Am writing a script which creates a directory but when i tried (Ruby script running on windows)

> destination = "path to the folder"
>
> FileUtils.mkdir_p destination

it gives me an error saying Permission Denied (Errno::EACCES) at mkdir_p

Any help is appreciated . Thank you

Comment: Well … do you *have* the required permissions?

Comment: Yes, I have given all the permissions , i redone everything from scratch but still that issue persists, looks like that has something to do with the code and how am writing but am not sure

Answer (score 2):

open your cmd terminal with administrator privileges, and then run the script again. It seems like your folder is in a place that need admin privileges, so you can create it. Also add it to your script:

```
require 'win32ole'

shell = WIN32OLE.new('Shell.Application')
shell.ShellExecute('path_to_ruby_program', nil, nil, 'runas')
```

And see this two questions:

[Run ruby script in elevated mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268154/run-ruby-script-in-elevated-mode)

[Detect if running with administrator privileges under Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560366/detect-if-running-with-administrator-privileges-under-windows-xp)

Comment: I tried doing that , i have given all the permissios or required permissions but still that is a problem ,

Comment: destination = "\\\\server\\usershares\\#{username}\\Documents\\"+userid.to_s+""
 


FileUtils.mkdir_p destination

Comment: @meher I updated the answer for you, add it to the script, and don't forget voting and accepting if you liked :)

Comment: looks like it was fixed by giving full control to that folder, anyways i will use the solution for my future tasks , Thank you

Comment: Sure, i did this time as well

Comment: @meher no problem! I have always loved to help, if the answer was useful don't forget in the future to accept (with the check box top left in the answer the  ✓ simbol)