# Check if an account is a member of a local group and perform an IF/ELSE in powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell

I was wondering how to best approach this.  Basically I have a script that needs to check if USER1 is a member of local Administrators and if so, remove it.  These groups are all local and the script will be run on the system I need to check (no remoting needed).

I was thinking something along the lines of capturing and evaluating the output from

```
net localgroup Administrators

test\user1
test\user2
```

However I am not sure how to capture the output for evaluation (pretty new to powershell).  Has anyone done something like this?  I really appreciate any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [powershell - list local users and their groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548476/powershell-list-local-users-and-their-groups)

Answer (score 7):

one way without module or snapin:

```
$group =[ADSI]"WinNT://./Administrators,group" 
$members = @($group.psbase.Invoke("Members")) 

($members | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -contains "Administrator"
```

this return `True` or `False` belong the case

to remove user Administrator from Administrators group:

```
$group.remove("WinNT://Administrator")
```

Comment: This does not quite work if a user is in a group which is an administrative group. The user would be an administrator in this case but would not show up as the Administrators group member

Comment: @zespri The OP ask how to check users in local Administrators group, if you need to check another local group you just need to change `Administrator` with the name of your local group in the first line of code.

Comment: The point is that a user can be an administrator without being in the local Administrators group. If he belongs to *any* group that is a member of the local Administrators group they will be a local admin. And you can't check it the shown way.

Comment: The best example are domain admins. They are local admins on your pc by merit of them being in the Domain Admins group and the Domain Admins group being a member of the local Administrators group. But of course the could be several levels of membership like this, not just one.

Comment: @zespri then you have to check membership of the domain user in the the 'domain admins' group i.e.: `([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole("Domain Admins")`

Comment: yep, but you would need to do this recursively, because Domain Admins group can have other groups, and other groups can be in the local admin group =)

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = (net localgroup administrators | Select-String 'testuser1' -SimpleMatch).ToString()
net localgroup administrators "$user" /delete
```

You're not using objects and you don't have a lot of error checking, but this is a pretty simple way to get what you want.