# Retrieving console output with admin privs (UAC)

Tags: ruby, windows, cmd, windows-10

tldr; ***I need to run a command as admin and retrieve the output***

I've already created a bat file that does the job but I want to translate it to pure ruby as a learning exercise. 
Using backticks I can get the output from the command, unfortunately the output tells me I lack the user privileges. Through this site I've found how to poke UAC in the right way, but I can't seem to get it to recognise the command I want which is (bcdedit /v)

I've read through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/shell-shellexecute & [Detect if running with administrator privileges under Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560366/detect-if-running-with-administrator-privileges-under-windows-xp)
 and numerous stack overflow posts with similar questions but haven't found clear guidelines to do this.

```
def running_in_admin_mode?
    (`reg query HKU\\S-1-5-19 2>&1` =~ /ERROR/).nil?
end

unless running_in_admin_mode? 
    shell = WIN32OLE.new('Shell.Application')
    shell.ShellExecute("ruby", File.expand_path(__FILE__), nil, 'runas')
    exit
end
```

update: so this sort of works. It flashes up the output I want in an IRB shell, but opens infinite new shells which locks up the computer.

```
require 'win32ole'

shell = WIN32OLE.new('Shell.Application')
shell.ShellExecute("ruby", File.expand_path(__FILE__), nil, 'runas')
response = `bcdedit /v`
p response
exit
```

Update: giving up doing it for now. Instead just checking the responses. Code is not completely functional yet, but here is where I am incase someone wants to pitch in.

```
require 'win32/registry'
require 'win32ole'

p 'Device Guard v0.1'
p 'Checking for requisite permissions'


def disable
p 'Would you like me to disable Docker and enable VMWare? [Yes] or [No]'
  case (gets.downcase.chomp)
  when 'yes'
    puts "Disabling docker"
    `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` # seems to work ok
    Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER.open('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run') do |reg|
      value = reg['Docker for Windows'] # need to save the location of the executable for next time
      reg.delete_value('Docker for Windows') # Access denied even when run as admin :()
    end
  when 'no'
  recheck
  else
  puts 'Instructions unclear'
  disable
  end
end

def enable
  p 'Would you like me to disable VMWare and enable Docker? [Yes] or [No]'
  case (gets.downcase.chomp)
  when 'yes'
    Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER.open('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run') do |reg|
      docker_location = reg['Docker for Windows']
      p docker_location
    `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype Auto`
end
  when 'no'
    recheck
  else
    puts "Instructions unclear"
    enable
  end
end

def recheck
  p 'Well what do you want me to do then? [Recheck] or [Exit]'
  case (gets.downcase.chomp)
  when 'recheck'
    startup
  when 'exit'
    puts "bye then"
    exit
  else
    puts "Instructions unclear"
    recheck
  end
end

def check_hypervisor(response)
  edited_response = response.match('hypervisorlaunchtype(.*)')[1]
  if edited_response.end_with?("    Off")
    p 'Hypervisor Launch Type is disabled'
    p 'This means VMWare should run and Docker is disabled'
    enable
  elsif edited_response.end_with?("    Auto")
    p 'Hypervisor Launch Type is enabled'
    p 'This means that Docker should run and VMWare is disabled'
    disable
  end
end

def startup
  response = `bcdedit /v`
  unless response.include?("Windows Boot Manager")
    no_access
  end

  unless response.include?("Access is denied")
    check_hypervisor(response)
  end
end

def no_access
  p 'I am not running as admin. Please run me from a shell with admin privilages'
  exit
end

startup
```

Comment: Please add any relevant MS/Windows tags, as this isn't just about Ruby.

Comment: The way something like this works typically is to have the program/script restart itself elevated if it lacks admin access. If it has to elevate, it should wait for the elevated instance to exit and use the same exit code. I can't help with the Ruby specifics.